# Do Hubspot form IDs need to be secure

Tags: hubspot

I'm cleaning up some config files to remove sensitive information from source control. Do I need to secure the form IDs that i'm sending data to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not need to hide them, the form IDs are meant to be exposed and even Portal IDs as well.
You can navigate to any website that is hosting an HS form and view the embed code to reveal either of those 2 attributes at any time.